# Select tag unaffected by negative margin

Tags: html, css, margin

Why do some elements ignore negative margins? In this case, I am specifically concerned with a `select` tag so I can position it more inline with the text of the paragraph it is in. Example:

```
<p>
  Paragraph with a select
  <select style="margin-top:-25px">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>
  inline
</p>
```

In this simple example, the `select` completely ignores the -25px top margin. Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you should be adjusting the select element's vertical-align rather than trying to nudge it around yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so much the tag's responsiveness to the margin, but the fact that the element is innately set to `display:inline`, which prevents vertical movement.

Comment: Try using `position:relative;top:-25px;` instead of the negative top margin.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the SELECT tag in a DIV, style the DIV.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. But, I had to apply `display:inline-block` to the div so it would remain inline with the rest of the text

Answer (score 0):

It's not the cleanest way, but I'd just wrap the  tag in a  and put the adjustments on the div.